# How to dynamically append to array in dict?

Tags: python

This has taken me over a day of trial and error. I am trying to keep a dictionary of queries and their respective matches in a search. My problem is that there can be one or more matches. My current solution is:

`match5[query_site]` will already have the first match but if it finds another match it will append it using the code below.

```
temp5=[]  #temporary variable to create array              
if isinstance(match5[query_site],list):  #check if already a list              
    temp5.extend(match5[query_site])
    temp5.append(match_site)
else:
    temp5.append(match5[query_site])
match5[query_site]=temp5 #add new location
```

That if statement is literally to prevent extend converting my str element into an array of letters. If I try to initialize the first match as a single element array I get `None` if I try to directly append. I feel like there should be a more pythonic method to achieve this without a temporary variable and conditional statement.

Update: Here is an example of my output when it works

```
5'flank: ['8_73793824', '6_133347883', '4_167491131', '18_535703', '14_48370386']
3'flank: X_11731384
```

There's 5 matches for my "5'flank" and only 1 match for my "3'flank".

Comment: what is `match_site`?

Comment: Could you not just by default have lists as values of `match5`? then you can simply append if `match_site` is not in the list yet. Or even better make it `set` values and use `add`. Or maybe I don't get what you want...

Comment: `match_site` is just a string

Comment: @jojo, I mentioned that above that when I tried to do `match5[query_site]=[match_site]` as the first instance I get `None` as my result.

Comment: what **is** your result and how do you get it? How exactly does `match5` initially look like?

Comment: it should be a single value or array (if multiple matches found) assigned to its respective entry in the dictionary. (ie `['apple', 'orange', 'peach']`). I updated above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what about this:

```
if query_site not in match5:  # here for the first time
   match5[query_site] = [match_site]
elif isinstance(match5[query_site], str):  # was already here, a single occurrence
    match5[query_site] = [match5[query_site], match_site]  # make it a list of strings
else:  # already a list, so just append
   match5[query_site].append(match_site)
```

Comment: technically I am trying to append `match_site` not `temp5`. `temp5` is just my temp array. I thought about this as well, but it creates a list of lists with the last element as a single element. (ie, `[[["hello","hi"],"world"],"there"]`)

Comment: @nchuang so if I get you right, you used `temp5` to switch to a list of values, right? I updated the answer, if I understand correctly what you want to do, you don't need `temp5` at all.

Comment: @nchuang you should really tell us how `match_site` really looks like. Is it just a string or a list of strings?

Comment: I updated the output above. `match_site` is a single str element. It is not a list.

Comment: @nchuang then, if `match_site` is a string, `match5` is a dictionary with either lists or strings as values, it is impossible that my answer produces something like `[[["hello","hi"],"world"],"there"]`. This could only happen if `match_site` is a list itself.

Comment: you were, it worked. I apologized for dismissing it initially. I had tried it before I am not sure why this time it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I like using `setdefault()` for cases like this.

```
temp5 = match5.setdefault(query_site, [])
temp5.append(match_site)
```

It's sort of like `get()` in that it returns an existing value if the key exists but you can provide a default value.  The difference is that if the key doesn't exist already `setdefault` inserts the default value into the dict.

Comment: This will give AttributeError that you are trying to call append on str object

Comment: If the code fragment I provide is always used to update `match5`, there will never be a bare string stored as a value in the dict.  The first item will be stored as a list with 1 element.  So no errors.   If `match5` is already populated with some other data the code would need to be generalized to support that.

Comment: the code fragment is used on `match5[query_site]` after it knows it already has at least one element. Yea, I saw setdefault as a solution for appending to a dictionary. I don't understand how this can be generalized?

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need to do

```
if query_site not in match5:
    match5[query_site] = []
temp5 = match5[query_site]
temp5.append(match_site)
```

You could also do

```
temp5 = match5.setdefault(query_site, [])
temp5.append(match_site)
```

Comment: `temp5` is my temporary variable. Seems like you are appending to the temp variable?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `match5` is a dictionary, what about this:

```
if query_site not in match5:  # first match ever
   match5[query_site] = [match_site]
else:  # entry already there, just append
   match5[query_site].append(temp5)
```

Make the entries of the dictionary to be *always* a list, and just append to it.

Comment: I've tried something like this but I get the cannot append to str error

Comment: `match5[query_site]` is a list. The `append` statement should work fine. Something I am missing? Do you have such example?

Comment: `[match5[query_site]]` is technically the list but even this does not work unless it is assigned to a variable. It is difficult for me to demonstrate this.